# DOMDocument Xpath add multiple container divs

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have the following that adds a container div to images within a 'p' container with a class of aligncenter...

```
$images = $xpath->query("//p/img[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' aligncenter ')]");
        foreach($images as $img) {
            $wrap = $dom->createElement("div");
            $wrap->setAttribute("class","inner ".$img->getAttribute("class"));
            $img->parentNode->replaceChild($wrap,$img);
            $wrap->appendChild($img);
        }
```

So the following...

Becomes...

```
<div class="inner">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

I am now trying to add another container so it becomes...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I iterate over the images again or can I modify the current code so that it adds another container div at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's definitely possible to do it all in one loop.  Assuming your current code works this should do the trick:

```
foreach($images as $img) {
    $outerWrap = $dom->createElement('div');
    $outerWrap->setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
    $wrap = $dom->createElement("div");
    $wrap->setAttribute("class","inner ".$img->getAttribute("class"));
    $img->parentNode->replaceChild($outerWrap,$img);
    $outerWrap->appendChild($wrap);
    $wrap->appendChild($img);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that saved a few cycles :)